# Can't click on a dropdown box in Selenium Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, xpath, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to download a file from the next webpage:

`https://www.superfinanciera.gov.co/SIMEV2/rnve/informesfinancierosniif/110/000001/0`

And can't get to the final page

My code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.superfinanciera.gov.co/SIMEV2/rnve')
busqueda_texto = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchBarRNVE"]/div/input')
busqueda_texto.send_keys(seleccion)
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchBarRNVE"]/div/a[2]/a/span'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cardRNVE"]'))).click()
time.sleep(3)
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dropdownMenuButton"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dropdownSubmenuButton"]/li[1]/a[11]'))).click()
time.sleep(3)

## AÑO
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="anioConsulta"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/app-layout-reportes-rnve/div/app-informes-financieros-niif/feature-toggle-provider/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]'))).click()

## TIPO DE REPORTE
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/app-layout-reportes-rnve/div/app-informes-financieros-niif/feature-toggle-provider/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/app-layout-reportes-rnve/div/app-informes-financieros-niif/feature-toggle-provider/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/option[2]'))).click()
```

The error i get is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-c1f3ee3cdf7e> in <cell line: 24>()
     22 WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/app-layout-reportes-rnve/div/app-informes-financieros-niif/feature-toggle-provider/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div'))).click()
     23 WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/app-layout-reportes-rnve/div/app-informes-financieros-niif/feature-toggle-provider/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div'))).click()
---> 24 WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/app-layout-reportes-rnve/div/app-informes-financieros-niif/feature-toggle-provider/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/option[2]'))).click()
     25 
     26 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     93             if time.monotonic() > end_time:
     94                 break
---> 95         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     96 
     97     def until_not(self, method, message: str = ""):

TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
#0 0x586cdb24e6b3 <unknown>
#1 0x586cdaf241e7 <unknown>
#2 0x586cdaf6b566 <unknown>
#3 0x586cdaf6b651 <unknown>
#4 0x586cdafa8a74 <unknown>
#5 0x586cdaf8d0ed <unknown>
#6 0x586cdafa6322 <unknown>
#7 0x586cdaf8ce93 <unknown>
#8 0x586cdaf5f934 <unknown>
#9 0x586cdaf6071e <unknown>
#10 0x586cdb213cb8 <unknown>
#11 0x586cdb217bf0 <unknown>
#12 0x586cdb22219c <unknown>
#13 0x586cdb218808 <unknown>
#14 0x586cdb1e527f <unknown>
#15 0x586cdb23ce88 <unknown>
#16 0x586cdb23d059 <unknown>
#17 0x586cdb24d843 <unknown>
#18 0x7f494be08b43 <unknown>
```

In the dropdown box called "Tipo de Reporte" I can't click on the second option. I tried by XPATH and CSS_SELECTOR, but always i get the same error.

Any help will be very appreciated .

NOTE: the XPATH i put in the code is the one that Chrome give me when i click "copy xpath" button.

Comment: thanks Freddy - well i am also facing some issues with colab and selenium. Did you solve this issue!? Look forward to hear from you

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it for anyone facing the same issue.

The solution is using JSExtractor:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.superfinanciera.gov.co/SIMEV2/rnve')
busqueda_texto = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchBarRNVE"]/div/input')
busqueda_texto.send_keys(seleccion)
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchBarRNVE"]/div/a[2]/a/span'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cardRNVE"]'))).click()
time.sleep(3)
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dropdownMenuButton"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dropdownSubmenuButton"]/li[1]/a[11]'))).click()
time.sleep(3)

## AÑO
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="anioConsulta"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/app-layout-reportes-rnve/div/app-informes-financieros-niif/feature-toggle-provider/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]'))).click()

## TIPO DE REPORTE
dropdown = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/app-layout-reportes-rnve/div/app-informes-financieros-niif/feature-toggle-provider/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', dropdown)
dropdown.click()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/app-layout-reportes-rnve/div/app-informes-financieros-niif/feature-toggle-provider/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/option[2]'))
```